# How to suppress a blank page at the end of a Crystal Report group

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I have a rather complex Crystal Report that is displaying a blank page at the end of each group. This is an issue as my customer requires the next group to start on the next page without a blank page in between.

The report has four groups; the blank page appears at the end of each Group 1. Group 1 has four sub-group headers that dynamically display on a page given an employee's group. There is one group footer for Group 1.

I do know it is not an issue of the details page bleeding into the next page and falsely creating a blank page; this is consistent with each Group 1.

Solutions I have tried:

- I have de-selected the option to display a "New Page After" in *both* the Section Expert and the Group Expert, *just* for Group 1 (as this is the group causing the issue).
- Also added a formula to the Group 1 footer to the "New Page After" formula to display `Not(OnLastRecord)`; the blank page remains
- Tried selecting and de-selecting the "Keep Together" options, in both the Section Expert and Group Expert

Some of these solutions switch the blank page to the start of Group 1. I have dynamic paging for each employee, and can see that page 1 of 4 for the first employee in each group is blank.

I am at a total loss here; all of my normal strategies for grouping logic have not worked. Also attempted each of these suggested with no luck:
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=16733

[Crystal Reports 11 - Useless blank page is added with just group headers that have data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346216/crystal-reports-11-useless-blank-page-is-added-with-just-group-headers-that-ha)

https://answers.sap.com/questions/4160531/a-blank-page-appears-after-the-group-header.html

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer for those building complex Crystal reports and troubleshooting this issue: the "Keep Together" option was selected for Group 2, which was adding in the extra page for the first person in each Group 1.